# Migrating an angular written extension to manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, manifest, chromium

as I've seen last month manifest V3 is now ready for production as google development team says. But I think that documentation is not complete (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration) or is not up to date. I am trying to learn how to develop an extension using angular,typescript and Webpack, but also , I want the extension to use manifest v3. I am using this tutorial as reference (https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/chrome-extension-with-angular-why-and-how-778200b87575). I somehow want to keep the same steps from this tutorial and not divert very much.
My extension is a generated angular project and my background in written in typescript and is compiled in js using Webpack.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Great Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension with Angular",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "webNavigation",
        "storage"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker":"background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "content_security_policy": {
      "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self' "
    }
}
```

background.ts

```
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ color: '#3aa757' });

  chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(() => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, ([{ id }]) => {
      chrome.pageAction.show(id);
    });
  }, { url: [{ urlMatches: 'google.com' }] });
});
```

custom-webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: { background: 'src/background.ts' },
}
```

My background.js looks like this:

```
if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
    (window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["background"],{
    
    /***/ "EtE5":
    /*!***************************!*\
      !*** ./src/background.ts ***!
      \***************************/
    /*! no static exports found */
    /***/ (function(module, exports) {
    
    var __read = (this && this.__read) || function (o, n) {
        var m = typeof Symbol === "function" && o[Symbol.iterator];
        if (!m) return o;
        var i = m.call(o), r, ar = [], e;
        try {
            while ((n === void 0 || n-- > 0) && !(r = i.next()).done) ar.push(r.value);
        }
        catch (error) { e = { error: error }; }
        finally {
            try {
                if (r && !r.done && (m = i["return"])) m.call(i);
            }
            finally { if (e) throw e.error; }
        }
        return ar;
    };
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ color: '#3aa757' });
        chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function () {
            chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (_a) {
                var _b = __read(_a, 1), id = _b[0].id;
                chrome.pageAction.show(id);
            });
        }, { url: [{ urlMatches: 'google.com' }] });
    });
    
    
    /***/ })
    
    },[["EtE5","runtime"]]]);
    //# sourceMappingURL=background.js.map
   
}
```

1. But if I try to load it in Google Canary chrome://extension I get an error saying that

```
window is not defined
```

I searched and found that window is not supported in service workers.

2. I tried using workbox with Webpack but again I get some google error saying.

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'addAll' on 'Cache': Request scheme 'chrome-extension'
```

I know that the background.js needs to be a service worker, but I just can't find any solution to fit my problem and help me.

Is there any solution for doing this in manifest V3 that actually works ?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

Adding `optimization.runtimeChunk = false` works in my case.

custom-webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: { background: 'src/background.ts' },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!! What exactly does "output: { filename: '[name].js' }" do? Because when I removed it my code still worked

Comment: I've add this option to remove the hash part in generated filename, but in https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/chrome-extension-with-angular-why-and-how-778200b87575, there a option "outputHashing": "none" in angular.json...
I remove this part, thanks for pointing me this point.